# How to get the label and caption of the current table environment?

Tags: cross-referencing

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{longtable,nameref}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[t]{l l} 
    \caption{Table caption.}
    \label{tab:table1}

    \\ a & b
    \\ c & \textit{\nameref*{tab:table1}}

\end{longtable}         

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use the caption of the current table in one cell without typing its label `tab:table1`, but rather using a "self-reference" like `\currentlabelname` -- provided that only one label and one caption are created in the current table environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `nameref` stores the titles in macro `\@currentlabelname`. However, it is stored locally, therefore it needs to be assigned to a global macro for use in other table cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{longtable,nameref}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[t]{l l}
    \caption{Table caption.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \global\expandafter
    \let\expandafter\captiontitle\csname @currentlabelname\endcsname
    \\ a & b
    \\ c & \textit{\captiontitle}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]